# SQLAlchemy Error when creating engine when using super() function

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, teradata

I'am using SQLAlchemy in order to connect to a teradata database with this function :

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
cnx = create_engine(engine+"://"+username+":"+password+"@"+host)
```

but I'm getting this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/sqlalchemy/engine/__init__.py", line 479, in create_engine
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py", line 98, in create
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/sqlalchemy_teradata/dialect.py", line 129, in create_connect_args
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/sqlalchemy_teradata/data_type_converter.py", line 13, in __init__
TypeError: super() argument 1 must be type, not classobj
```

This has worked for me for python 2.7.11 perfectly but now when executing it on python 2.7.13, I'am not even understanding the error.

FI :

this how data_type_converter.py looks like:

```
from teradata.datatypes import DefaultDataTypeConverter

class TDDataTypeConverter(DefaultDataTypeConverter):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TDDataTypeConverter, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def _process_data_type(self, dataType):
        if 'INTERVAL' in dataType:
            return dataType.replace('_', ' ')
        return dataType

    def convertValue(self, dbType, dataType, typeCode, value):
        dataType = self._process_data_type(dataType)
        return super(TDDataTypeConverter, self).convertValue(
            dbType, dataType, typeCode, value)
```

Also cthe create_engine() function works when connexting to Postgres database

Comment: You are using Python 2, I presume? Then you must use new-style classes for `super` to work, but `TDDataTypeConverter` is an old-style class. To make it new-style, simply explicitly inherit from `object`, so in the class definition, do `class TDDataTypeConverter(object): ...` better yet, use Python 3.

Comment: Using Python 3 is definitely preferred. With 64-bit Python 3 you could also use the newer, officially supported teradatasql dialect (teradatasqlalchemy package). If you must use Python 2, in principle you should probably use multiple inheritance, i.e.`class TDDataTypeConverter(DefaultDataTypeConverter,object):`